# Read a pipe delimited field into dynamic fields oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am facing a challenge when reporting from my audit table which has a modified fields data in this format:

```
MODIFIED_FIELDS_DATA
Name|Stanley|mike|Location|London|Moscow|Age|20|24
```

That field shows the modified field, Old value and the new value. For example this means that the field Name has been changed from Stanley to Mike, Location has been changed from London to Moscow and so on..

I intent to read the field and report it :

```
FIELD| OLD_VALUE| NEW_VALUE |FIELD2 OLD_VALUE2 | NEW_VALUE2 |FIELD3 OLD_VALUE3| NEW_VALUE3
Name | Stanley| Mike  Location|London|Moscow|Age|20|24
```

Anyone who can give me ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: You can use [SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/3931/0Z), add field/old_value/new_value as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/3931/0Z)**

```
with temp as
(
    select 1 AS id,'Name|Stanley|mike|Location|London|Moscow|Age|20|24' AS col  from dual
)
select 
  id
  ,trim(regexp_substr(t.col, '[^|]+', 1, 1)) AS FIELD1 
  ,trim(regexp_substr(t.col, '[^|]+', 1, 2)) AS OLD_VALUE 
  ,trim(regexp_substr(t.col, '[^|]+', 1, 3)) AS NEW_VALUE 
  ,trim(regexp_substr(t.col, '[^|]+', 1, 4)) AS FIELD2 
  ,trim(regexp_substr(t.col, '[^|]+', 1, 5)) AS OLD_VALUE2 
  ,trim(regexp_substr(t.col, '[^|]+', 1, 6)) As NEW_VALUE2 
  ,trim(regexp_substr(t.col, '[^|]+', 1, 7)) AS FIELD3 
  ,trim(regexp_substr(t.col, '[^|]+', 1, 8)) As OLD_VALUE3 
  ,trim(regexp_substr(t.col, '[^|]+', 1, 9)) AS NEW_VALUE3
from 
  temp t,
  table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(t.col, '[^|]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
GROUP BY id;
```

**EDIT**

You example `Name|Stanley||Location|Moscow||London` doesn't make sense because it has 7 values not 6 but you can use:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/4055/0)**

```
select 1 AS id,REPLACE('Name|Stanley||Location|Moscow||London','||', '| |') AS col  from dual
```

to handle empty values.

Comment: This does not work if I have a blank pipe e.g `Name|Stanley||Location|Moscow||London`

Comment: @ErrorNotFoundException See updated answer and next time specify exactly that you can have case like this